# Regex works alone but not when used in groups

Tags: python, regex

The main problem is when I try to create a regex compounded by different groups I can get the values for each group.

I have a string like this:

```
some text here en Value1 (VALUE2)
```

I want to create a regex to get three substrings:

1. `some text here`. Is everything that is between the start of the string and the word `en`.
2. `Value1`. Is the text between `en` and the first `(`.
3. `Value2`. Is the text between `()`.

I've searched information about groups and I've read:

> They are created by placing the characters to be grouped inside a set of parentheses (, ).

> Anything you have in parentheses () will be a capture group.

> We can specify as many groups as we wish. Each sub-pattern inside a pair of parentheses will be captured as a group.

So I assume I need a regex with three groups (i.e. three `()` where every bracket contains the regex for each case).

So my idea was: Look for a every regex you need and add together with `()` to create the groups. So I've used these regex for the groups:

1. First group: `.+?(?= en)` [example](https://regex101.com/r/koUogK/1)
2. Second group: `(?<=en\s).*?(?=\s\()` [example](https://regex101.com/r/wZC2sU/1)
3. Third group: `(?<=\().+?(?=\))` [example](https://regex101.com/r/7skwQV/1)

But when I try all regex together:

```regex
(.+?(?= en))((?<=en\s).*?(?=\s\())((?<=\().+?(?=\)))
```

It not get the groups. Actually it nof found any group ([example](https://regex101.com/r/sPhjev/1)).

I don't know if I'm missing something about the use of groups in regex but I can't get the way to do it.

Also, my python code is:

```py
import re

str = "some text here en Value1 (VALUE2)"
result = re.search(r"(.+?(?= en))((?<=en\s).*?(?=\s\())((?<=\().+?(?=\)))", str)

print(result.groups())
```

And yes, I know I can iterate over the string and get values, but I want to do it with `regex` if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*?)\s+en\s+(.*?)\s+\(([^()]*)\)
```

If `VALUE1` is always a chunk of non-whitespace chars you can use

```
^(.*?)\s+en\s+(\S+)\s+\(([^()]*)\)
#              ^^^
```

If the pattern must match the whole string:

```
^(.*?)\s+en\s+(\S+)\s+\(([^()]*)\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/06zTjk/1).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/s4GiPp):

```py
import re
text = "some text here en Value1 (VALUE2)"
result = re.search(r"^(.*?)\s+en\s+(.*?)\s+\(([^()]*)\)", text)
print(result.groups())
# => ('some text here', 'Value1', 'VALUE2')
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+en\s+` - `en` enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` (replace with `.*` if there can be any chars and you want to match till the rightmost occurrence of `)`)
- `\)` - a `)` char.